# How to get trigger a command when an inline button is pressed?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

```
async def start (update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Reserve", callback_data = "/reserve")
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await update.message.reply_text("Hello! Thank you for choosing (Business Name), this bot is automated to book your appointments with us.", reply_markup = reply_markup)

async def reserve(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Week 1", callback_data = "WEEK1"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Week 2", callback_data = "WEEK2"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Week 3", callback_data = "WEEK3"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Week 4", callback_data = "WEEK4"),
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await update.mesage.reply_text("October", reply_markup = reply_markup)
```

I can't seem to find a solution to enable

```
InlineKeyboardButton("Reserve", callback_data = "/reserve")
```

to trigger the reserve command when pressed.

I have read multiple articles about the callbackquery but I don't understand why I can't seem to get it, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: please have a look at [this example](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.5/examples.inlinekeyboard.html).